# Spring boot is it some way to establish session(flow) context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I suppose my question is very simple, but still..

I have my Spring boot application with some endpoints:

- REST
- Kafka consumers
- etc...

Some of them are using the same logic, so I need some mechanism, some context per action (session context, I don't know), where I can save some common data (sessionId, some user's data for example, ~10-15 variables) to be accessible from the all logic.

For example if I have call hierarchy like this:
Class1->Class2->Class3->Class4 I don't want to pull this 15 variables through all 4 classes to use it in the Class2 and Class4. I want to put it into some local session before executing of Class1 on the start of the logic and to have possibility to access this data on all layers.

I understand, that I can write something like this by myself or use ThreadLocal, but I'm pretty sure that It's already should be implemented.